# Do humans hear the beat frequency or the average frequency or just individual frequencies?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

We have two sound sources of the same amplitude but of slightly different frequencies : $f_1$ and $f_2$. When they are sounded simultaneously what would be the frequency that an observer hears ?

I have seen mixed answers for this question.

One answer is that $|f_1-f_2|$ is the frequency with which the resultant intensity varies, but not the frequency that one hears. The frequency that one hears would be $\frac{|f_1+f_2|}{2}$ .

There's another answer which says that it would be $\frac{|f_1-f_2|}{2}$ .

Another one which simply says $|f_1-f_2|$ .

What is the actual frequency that one would hear and what is the frequency of the resultant intensity ?

Answer (score -1):

The frequency that an observer "hears" is a physiological and not a physical response. If the two frequencies are "far enough apart", our brain interprets them as two distinct frequencies. If they are "close together" we are hearing "beat tones" that are customarily said to have a frequency that is the difference between the two tones. That may or may not be so, because humans can hear beating at e.g. 15Hz difference, but we can't actually count that fast. I suspect that somebody has done experiments where they play a third tone at or near the beating frequency and evaluate the responses of the kind "That tone was lower/higher than the beating frequency", but other than that I am not sure that we can actually do a "frequency measurement" with our hearing in any rational way.
For really low beating frequencies (that we probably can "count") we can assume that our "amplitude detector" kicks in. Since the sum of two frequencies can be decomposed as $$sin(a)+sin(b)=2sin((a+b)/2)cos((a-b)/2)$$ we are going to hear a slow amplitude modulation of the average frequency (but again... since most of us don't have absolute hearing, what frequency we are really hearing in a particular case is up for guesses). I am not sure there is a simple answer in general that is not dependent on absolute frequencies and amplitudes.

From a physical perspective "beating" does not exist. Two tones are a two-tone spectrum. A hundred tones are a hundred-tone spectrum.

The physically more interesting question is what happens in non-linear systems that are excited by such a spectrum. In that case we will, indeed, find a mix of frequency components at $f_0, f_1, 2f_0, 2f_1, f_0 + f_1, f_0 - f_1$ and higher non-linear products.